# Default Applications for LXSession not working correctly Lubuntu 14.04.2?

Tags: lubuntu, lxsession

Whenever I change a Default Application in LXSession from "Disabled" to a Program, such as LibreOffice Calc for the Spreadsheet, it always reverts back to "Disabled", or to some other Program, such as LibreOffice Math, which isn't even in the List. This also happens with the Image Viewer and the Audio Player. Both either revert back to "Disabled" or to some other Program which isn't even on the List. It doesn't matter if I reboot or log out and log back in or even if I change the Program manually, it still reverts back to "Disabled" or to some other Program not on the List.

In regards to the file: ~/.config/lxsession-default-apps/settings.conf

Any changes I make to this file are not being saved upon reboot or logging out and logging back in. Changes are saved prior to reboot or logout. However, upon logging back in or rebooting, no changes are saved and the entire file reverts back to the exact way it was prior to reboot or log out and so do the respective LXSession default Program issues.

Is there a way to fix this so the correct Program displays and doesn't revert back to "Disabled"?

Thank you for any assistance you may be able to provide.